# What namespace has JObject in json.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

What namespace has JObject  in json.net?

Just installed int and can't seem to find that class?

Answer (score 15):

[JObject Class > Namespaces > Newtonsoft.Json.Linq > JObject](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)